# Implementing Laplace expansion in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran95

I have to write a program that solves linear equations with the Cramer method, and ask specifically to find the determinant with the Laplace expansion.

```
det A    = sum on i=1...N:(-1)**(i+1) a_i1 det ||A||_i1
```

where `||A||_i1` is the cofactor matrix of `A`, a `n-1 X n-1` matrix, created by eliminating the `i` row and 1 column.
and that's where I'm stuck.

This is what I wrote so far

```
 integer, parameter :: rk= selected_real_kind(6)
end module prec


module lap
  use prec
implicit none

contains
  recursive function det(a,n) result (d)
    real(kind=rk), intent(in), dimension(n,n) :: a
    real(kind=rk), dimension(n-1,n-1) :: b
  real(kind=rk) :: d
  integer ::i
  integer, intent(in)::n



if (size(a) > 4) then
  do i=1,n
 b(1:(i-1),:) = a(1:(i-1),:)
 b(i:n,:) = a((i+1):n,:)
 b(:,:) = a(:,2:n) 
    d= ((-1)**(i+1))*a(i,1)*det(b,n)
end do
    else
      d = a(1,1)*a(2,2)-a(1,2)*a(2,1)

      end if
  end function det
end module lap




      program sistema
```

it keeps telling me that I have non-conformant arrays, even though I'm using the subsets (and my professor says it's quite easy to obtain |A| with subsets).

Comment: Where is it that the compiler complains?  I'll also note that there are chunks of your example seemingly missing.

Comment: What you wrote so far seems to be the last two lines of a module called `prec`, a module called `lap` and the first line of a program called `sistema`.  You need to be much clearer about what your code is and precise about what error messages your compiler emits.  And at what lines in the source.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see the portions of your code that are missing. However, I think I see the problem:

With dimensions `a(n,n)` and `b(n-1,n-1)`, you cannot do `b(1:(i-1),:) = a(1:(i-1),:)` because the sizes of second dimension do not match. You should check the definition of a cofactor matrix - you should be removing a *column* as well as a *row*. Instead of the the three lines setting b, you should try:

```
b(1:(i-1),:) = a(1:(i-1),2:n)
b(i:n,:) = a((i+1):n,2:n)
```

Edit: damn, I always mix up row and column. Perhaps I mean remove a *row* instead of a *column*?

Comment: @francescalus I should have made it more clear that that line should be taken out. Edited and thanks.

Comment: He does this in also in `b(:,:) = a(:,2:n)` where the dimensions mismatch on the first dimension (n-1 vs n).